# Eloquent query, select specific column from relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to select a specific column from a relationship.

F.x

```
User::with(array('phone' => function($q) {
 $q->where('ext', "!=" 42);
}))->select('id', 'number');
```

Here i ONLY want to select the user ID, and the number for the phone.

How can i do that?

Keep in mind, there is over 2m users and 100m numbers, which is why i only want the user id and the number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
User::with(array('phone' => function($q) {
 $q->where('ext', "!=", 42);
 $q->select('id', 'number');
}));
```

Or

```
User::with('phone:id,number')->get();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood; I want the ID from ``User`` table, and the number from ``Phone`` table. Not the ID and number from Phone table. But thanks!

Comment: Do the same or send what models and relationships you have.

Comment: I think User::with(array('phone' => function($q) {
 $q->where('ext', "!=", 42);
 $q->select('number');
}))->select('id'); do the job.

Comment: Okay, but how do i extract `number` ? When i try to run the query with `->first()` it returns the relationship, but it's empty. However the user has numbers.

Comment: if i remove the `$q->select('number');` then i can see it.

Comment: Did you tried simply $model->number ?

Answer (score 0):

```
User::with(array('phone' => function($q) {
    $q->where('ext', '!=', 42)->select('id', 'number');
}))
->select('users.id', 'phone.number')
->get();
```